# When did the Jews cry out about their king in fulfillment of Shmuel's prophecy?

Tags: nevua-prophecy, samuel-shmuel-book-of, malchut-royalty, shmuel--the-man

In 1 Shmuel 8 Shmuel the Navi explains the laws of the king to the Jewish people and concludes with an apparent prophecy in pasuk 18:

> וּזְעַקְתֶּם֙ בַּיּ֣וֹם הַה֔וּא מִלִּפְנֵ֣י מַלְכְּכֶ֔ם אֲשֶׁ֥ר בְּחַרְתֶּ֖ם לָכֶ֑ם וְלֹא־יַעֲנֶ֧ה יְהֹוָ֛ה אֶתְכֶ֖ם בַּיּ֥וֹם הַהֽוּא׃

> The day will come when you cry out because of the king whom you yourselves have chosen; and the LORD will not answer you on that day.

I would like to know when this prophecy was fulfilled.

Comment: There were many many evil Kings in Melachim etc, and you will quite easily find examples of all of the bad things Hashem promises Kings will do. Because of that, it might be hard to answer this question with straightfoward answer

Comment: @RabbiKaii if the people are crying out because of something else an evil king did it would not be a fulfillment of the prophecy.  AFAIK, there is no example in Tanach of the people crying out because of the items listed by Shmuel

Comment: Negative prophecies don't have to come true (Rambam, *Hil. Y'sodei HaTorah* 10:4). Indeed, in this particular case, the Jewish People expressed contrition, and Sh'mu'eil seems to suggest that the previous harsh decree may have been revoked (1 Sh'mu'eil 12). Nonetheless, as @RabbiKaii observed, the Jewish People did suffer from wicked kings, and it is possible that not all the details of their suffering and crying out over the generations were recorded. The particular incident with Navos in 1 M'lachim 21 does seem reminiscent of Sh'mu'eil's warning: "ואת שדותיכם ואת כרמיכם וזיתיכם הטובים יקח".